# How do I get the EventType with the most recent EventDate?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml document with 2 EventTypes. I would like to display the `EventType` with the most recent `EventDate`

**Desired output**

```
<EventType eventDate="05/12/2015" eventTime="7:36 AM" noticeTypeCode="SFTP">DL reinstatement request to DPS - Fail to Pay</EventType>
```

**How do I do it by modifying my xslt code?**

**My xml document**

```
    <Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="DL Notice to DVS" MessageID="67094086" xmlns="">
    <Case InternalID="161709" ID="1218" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
        <CaseEvent Date="05/11/2015" ID="160825556" InternalEventID="1721874614" xmlns:reslib="urn:reslib">
            <EventDate>05/11/2015</EventDate>
            <EventTime>3:42 PM</EventTime>
            <Deleted>false</Deleted>
            <EventType Word="DLSUSFTP">DL suspension request to DPS - Fail to Pay</EventType>
        </CaseEvent>
        <CaseEvent Date="05/12/2015" ID="160825565" InternalEventID="1721874622" xmlns:reslib="urn:reslib">
            <EventDate>05/12/2015</EventDate>
            <EventTime>7:36 AM</EventTime>
            <Deleted>false</Deleted>
            <EventType Word="DLREINSNON">DL reinstatement request to DPS Nonresident-Compact State</EventType>
        </CaseEvent>
    </Case>
</Integration>
```

**My xsl code**

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Integration/Case/CaseEvent[(Deleted='false') and ((EventType/@Word='DLSUSFTP') or (EventType/@Word='DLREINSNON '))]">
    <xsl:sort select="substring(EventDate,7,4)" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:sort select="substring(EventDate,1,2)" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:sort select="substring(EventDate,4,2)" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:sort select="substring-after(EventTime,' ')" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:sort select="substring-before(EventTime,':')" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
    <xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(EventTime,':'),' ')" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to note is that there is currently a small typo in the expression in your `xsl:for-each`

```
(EventType/@Word='DLREINSNON ')
```

You have a spurious space in the string, meaning it won't match the event type you have shown in your XML.

Anyway, you have got the right approach by using `<xsl:if test="position() = 1">`, so now you just need to add the code to copy the `EventType` element

```
<xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <xsl:copy-of select="EventType"/>
</xsl:if>
```

However, looking at your expected output, you actually want to transform the `EventType` element you output too. In which case, you can use `xsl:apply-templates` here instead.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Integration/Case/CaseEvent[(Deleted='false') and ((EventType/@Word='DLSUSFTP') or (EventType/@Word='DLREINSNON'))]">
      <xsl:sort select="substring(EventDate,7,4)" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="substring(EventDate,1,2)" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="substring(EventDate,4,2)" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="substring-after(EventTime,' ')" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="substring-before(EventTime,':')" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(EventTime,':'),' ')" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="EventType"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EventType">
    <EventType eventDate="{../EventDate}" eventTime="{../EventTime}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </EventType>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) in creating the attribute values.

Comment: Tim, thank you again for your help. I had posted something saying my question was not answered but you did answer it.